# Can I read integers from a file that has both characters and integers from a byte array?

Tags: java

I've been looking for a way to print integers from a file which is supposed to have both integer and characters. I stored the integers and characters in an array called byte. I haven't been able to print the integers alone, as the ASCII value of all the characters is printed. Is there any way to get around this?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class readint
{
    public static void main()throws IOException
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        byte letter[]={'h','e','l',68,'l','o',1,2};
        FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("Integer.txt");
        fout.write(letter);
        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("Integer.txt");
        int p;
        String str="";
        System.out.println(sc.next());
        boolean b;
        while((p=fin.read())!=-1 && (b=sc.hasNextInt())==true)
        {
            System.out.print(p+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this, because all letters are translated to their ascii values, and you can't distinguish between 'D' and 68. (But if your integers are < 127, you can encode them as negatives).

Comment: You could change `byte letter[]={'h','e','l',68,'l','o',1,2};` to a `List<String>` that would hold both numbers and characters. So if you don't care about the type of letter then that should work: `List<String> letter = List.of("h", "e", "l","68", "l", "o", "1", "2")` as in your example.

Comment: Both your title and your code are confusing.  Do you want to read from a file, or do you want to read from System.in?  Why are you trying to do both?